# what tools can I use to quickly show/hide some reminding info for myself?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, alias

I'm using i3wm on Ubuntu 16.04, which I've defined some shortcut key mappings, and I also defined a lot of aliases in zsh.  Sometimes, I'll forget some of my key mapping or aliases, so I was wondering whether there's some tools which can show some custom information on screen, like my key mappings or aliases when I forget them. And I can toggle display the information very quickly.

Comment: What distribution are you using ??

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention I'm on ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Please change your question, and include in it that you are under Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

You can use sticky notes. Here is a preview :

[image]

You can show them and hide them very quickly, just by clicking on their little icon in the panel and choose `hide all`, `show all`.

## Installation

If you are using ubuntu, you can use this commands to install them :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:umang/indicator-stickynotes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-stickynotes
```

Or manually download the deb from [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/10/install-sticky-notes-indicator-ubuntu-14-10/) and install it.

Comment: I was just going to suggest `xpostit`, but I'm a bit older and didn't know about `stickynotes`, which might appeal to the modern desktop user more.